# ASP.Net GridView- DataBind method does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a grid view that I am trying to populate using a list of custom objects. However, the grid is not getting populated.

Below are the code excerpts:

**.ASPX File:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvResult" runat="server" ondatabound="gvResult_DataBound" 
                    onrowdatabound="gvResult_RowDataBound" 
                    onrowdeleting="gvResult_RowDeleting" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="Id"/>                            
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Regular Expression" DataField="RegExpression"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MatchedPart" DataField="MatchedPart"/>                                                        
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My object is defined as follows:

```
public class MatchedRegexObject
{

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string RegExpression { get; set; }

    public string MatchedPart { get; set; }
}
```

**This is my .ASPX.CS file**

```
List<MatchedRegexObject> matchedRegexObj = new List<MatchedRegexObject>();
//Populate matchedRegexObj
gvResult.DataSource = matchedRegexObj;
gvResult.DataBind();
```

It works perfectly fine when I set "AutoGenerateColumns" property to true. However when I provide custom column names by setting "AutoGenerateColumns" property to false, the grid does not appear. Can anyone help?

Comment: You might want to convert your List into a datatable?

Comment: You changed `AutoGenerateColumns` from True to False.  Is that the only change you made between the working and the non-working versions?

Comment: I copied your code and it worked just fine for me. Are you sure you aren't doing anything weird in your event handlers? If you strip the GridView down to its most basic form, does it still not work?

Comment: @AnnL. I changed "AutoGenerateColumns" to false and added columns to the grid using "ColumnCollection" property. I set each of the columns as a boundfield.

Comment: Try turning `AutoGenerateColumns` back on, and see if the grid reappears. If it doesn't, your problem is probably something other than that property having been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Why c# tag ?

c# like this ;

```
string query = "Select * From databasetablename";//Sample query
MySqlDataAdapter adaptor = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connectionname);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adaptor.Fill(table);
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to bind a gridview to a list with no elements.
could you do something similar to this:

```
List<MatchedRegexObject> matchedRegexObj = new List<MatchedRegexObject>();
//Populate matchedRegexObj
MatchedRegexObject m = new MatchedRegexObject();
m.Id = "id1";
m.MatchedPart = "Matchpart1";
m.RegExpression = "RegEx1";
matchedRegexObj.Add(m);
gvResult.DataSource = matchedRegexObj;
gvResult.DataBind();
```

Let me know how it goes.
cheers1